# Como manter selecionado a ultima seleção de um radiobutton do Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Existe alguma forma de manter selecionada a ultima opção clicada em botões do tipo `radiobutton` na lib `Tkinter` em Python?
Gostaria de, mesmo ao fechar o programa, quando abrir-se ele novamente, a opção estivesse selecionada.

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM4',9600, timeout=1)
time.sleep(2)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("LED RGB CONTROL - RAMON BASILIO PROJECT")
root.geometry("600x120")
root.configure(background="#12AEFF")

v = tk.IntVar()
v.set(0)  # initializing the choice, i.e. Python

colors = [
    "LED_1",
    "LED_2",
    "LED 1/LED 2",
    "NONE"
]

def ShowChoice():
    print(v.get())
    if v.get() == 0:
        ser.write(b'0')

    if v.get() == 1:
        ser.write(b'1')

    if v.get() == 2:
        ser.write(b'2')

    if v.get() == 3:
        ser.write(b'3')    

tk.Label(root, 
         text="Choose what Led will turn on",
         background = "#12AEFF",
         padx = 20).pack(anchor=tk.W)

for val, color in enumerate(colors):
    tk.Radiobutton(root, 
                  text=color,
                  indicatoron = 0,
                  width = 20,
                  padx = 20, 
                  variable=v, 
                  command=ShowChoice,
                  value=val).pack(anchor=tk.W)
root.mainloop()
```

O código básico é esse. Minha intenção é fazer uma GUI para controlar uma fita de LED endereçável que vou instalar no meu PC. A fita de LED por sua vez está conectada a um Arduino. O que eu queria era manter fixa a ultima escolha, mesmo depois de fechar e abrir a janela.

Comment: A única maneira que me vem a mente é salvar uma espécie de arquivo de configuração. Toda vez que iniciar, carregue ele com as configs salvas. Sempre se atentando à possibilidades de o usuário apagar o arquivo de configuração ou estiver mal formatado.

Comment: Pode até ser formatos conhecidos, como json ou xml.